# Different URLs to default extbase actions

Tags: typo3, seo, extbase, typo3-11.x

### TLDR;

TYPO3 extbase route enhancers generate different links to the same default action depending on whether the link definition explicitly names the action or not. E.g. menu → `x/` and fluid link generation → `x/list/`.

This is bad for search engines and I want to know how to fix it!

### Example

Consider this section of a site configuration:

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  xxx:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Xxx
    plugin: Yyy
    defaultController: 'Zzz::list'
    routes:
      - routePath: '/list/'
        _controller: 'Zzz::list'
      - routePath: '/details/{ddd-title}/'
        _controller: 'Zzz::detail'
        _arguments:
          ddd-title: ddd
    aspects:
      ddd-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_xxx_domain_model_ddd'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
        routeFieldPrefix: '/'
```

Then on a page with slug `/ppp/` the plugin `Yyy` is used to show a list of `ddd`s (e.g. `ddd`s could be cars or something) and if you click on an item (a car) then it shows the `detail` action for that item, identified by `ddd-title` on the same page in the same plugin.

This is relatively straightforward and I would expect the page menu of the website to show `https://domain.tld/ppp/` as the link to the list, which it does, so this works perfectly.

And if you click on an item on `https://domain.tld/ppp/` then that has the URL `https://domain.tld/ppp/details/some-ddd-title/` which is great.

But if I place a `<f:link.action action="list">back</f:link.action>` on the details page, then that does *not* lead back to `https://domain.tld/ppp/` but instead to `https://domain.tld/ppp/list/`. The worst thing is, that both URLs work and show the same content but have different canonical tags!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can actually delete this part

> routePath: '/list/'  
>    _controller: 'Zzz::list'

and it will work as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But sadly I tried that and the result is that the `<f:link.action />` view helper doesn't use route enhancers then at all (basically ignoring that there is a `defaultController`), so the resulting link then has a `cHash` and everything.